# Multilanguage support in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, multilingual

I'm using Django and I need to support multilanguage in my Javascript code. But my Javascript files are into site_media so they are not rendering by the template engine. I would like to learn what is the most common solution for this situation, how do you handle it generally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [l10n.js](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/localization-in-javascript) library I've written. The benefits are that you can separate language data files and code in a way that only optionally requires l10n.js.